# How to use an ImageView without de/allocating memory

Tags: android, eclipse, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an application that uses a flip-book style animation with thousands of images. APK size isn't an issue due to it being an internal only application that will never be put on any app store.

The issue I am having is my animator is a sub-classed **ImageView** that switches out images at 15 frames per second and each time I call **setImageURI** Garbage Collection then runs. So is there an alternative method to **setImageURI** that wont cause Garbage Collection to be run?

Edit: A little more background information.

My app has ~12 sequences and 6 of them contain 1609 Images and different events need to be called at certain frames. Another need is for the user to be able to stop on any frame to survey the situation and either preform an action or continue down the sequence. A 3D engine would have been the ideal solution but this method was brought up as the user doesn't need complete freedom and is on a "rail" the entire time.

This is the meat of the application and where the problem occurs

```
try {
   ((BitmapDrawable) getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
   setImageURI(imgUri);
   refreshDrawableState();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call recycle on the bitmap when you change the image.  The ImageView does that for you.  The problem is the same though.  You're losing the reference to the Bitmap, so the GC needs to run to collect it.  The only way to prevent that from happening is to keep the reference to the bitmap outside the ImageView and deallocate it when you have time to collect it without the user noticing.

Comment: @DeeV - Keeping them in memory is a bit of an issue since  my ~130mb jpgs get expanded to 2.7mb each. At that rate ~190 frames or 13 seconds will eat through more memory than there is ram on the device.

Comment: Then you have a contradicting problem because you need memory to continue, but you can't get memory unless you deallocate, but every time you deallocate a bitmap, the GC will run.  The GC will run whenever it decides to run.  You have limited control over when it will run.  The SoftReference suggestion would mitigate that by only deallocating when memory is NEEDED rather than just when the GC decides it's time to go.

You could allocate bitmaps in the C++ environment which bypasses the JVM and doesn't count toward your quota.  You're still limited by hardware though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Garbage Collector is running because you're exchanging one image for another which dumps the previous.  It's going to happen every time you lose references to the images.

Here are a couple possible methods to consider.

1. Since you mentioned it's a flipbook, build and assign an [AnimationDrawable](http://androidforums.com/application-development/11620-programmatic-frame-frame-animation-examle-animationdrawable.html) to the `ImageView` which will act as a frame-by-frame animation (exactly what a flipbook is).  This loads all the images at once and will keep them around until you lose a reference to the `AnimationDrawable`.
2. Store all the images as [SoftReferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) to cache the images.  A SoftReference will keep the object in memory until memory is needed to be collected.  This will slow the frequency of the garbage collector (assuming this is the cause).  Use `BitmapFractory` to build the image and `setImageBitmap` to assign it to the `ImageView`.  The other advantage of this is it allows you to build images on threads before you assign it to the ImageView.

Comment: Method #2 is the "best" solution for me as a simple flip book is a bit to limited for my stop/start/start from frame num x/resume needs. Android ended up not working for what I needed as my frames ended up being to large no matter what I tried so I switched to Windows based tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because your Image need to much memory, and the android need call the GB to free more mem trying to avoid crashing your program